# How single event works in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Without Jetpack Compose I am used to using `LiveData` then observe it, and when it changes, I do UI change (navigation, state, toast). But observe method in `LiveData` need owner.

Answer (score 1):

If your LiveData is in a view model, you can observe it from any composable function like this, and navigate when the value of the `LiveData` changes:

```
val observedData: Boolean by viewModel.navigate.observeAsState(false)

if (observedData) {
    navController.navigate("destination")
}

// reset the value of navigate in the view model
```

Comment: I want to do something when value change not to use it as state for composable function

Comment: The value of `observedData` will update when the value of your `LiveData` updates. You can then use it anywhere to change your UI, or can do whatever you like, if that is what you asked for.

Comment: I want to navigate when the value change,not to use value as state

Comment: If you have a `Boolean` value in the view model, you can do that. Change the value in the view model, observe it in the composable. When the value change, navigate. Reset the value in the view model.

Comment: how can I observe it

Answer (score 0):

In your viewModel you can use an event channel like this

```
val events = Channel<Event>(Channel.BUFFERED)
```

And in your composable, you can consume it this way

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
scope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
     viewModel.events.consumeEach { event -> handleEvents(event) }}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you do not want to assign an owner to the observer, you can use the `observeForever{...}`call, or else, passing in the activity itself is always a viable option.

Good luck!